# Set comprehension for element having largest value

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given a set of elements, $g \in G$, and a function $f(g)$ that returns a scalar, I would like to use set comprehension notation to find the set $S$ that includes:

- The element $g$ that has the largest value of $f(g)$ of any $g \in G$
- All elements that have a value of $f(g) \geq 0.5$

and no other elements.

What would this look like written in set notation?

Comment: It is my pleasure to inform you that your application is approved, and you're hereby authorized to use set comprehension notation to find that set. Enjoy your day!

Comment: (Did you also mean to ask a _question_ though, perchance? If so, you seem to have forgotten that).

Comment: Thank you for being sarcastic.  I hope my edit is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may formalize it as $$S := \{g \in G \ |\  \forall g' \in G : f(g) \geq f(g') \} \cup \{g \in G \ |\  f(g) \geq 0.5 \},$$ for example.

But note that the first set does not have to be a singleton set; it may even be empty, even if $G \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: Thank you, can you give an example of how first set be empty even if $G$ is non-empty?

Comment: Let $G := \mathbb{N}$, and let $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $f(n) := n$; or take $f(n) := 1-\frac{1}{n+1}$.